# How to remove Google Search engine placeholder (Cse)

Tags: jquery, css, google-custom-search

I am trying to remove the placeholder of the google search engine using **jquery** `addClass` and **css**.

Website url: https://gragop.herokuapp.com

**Inspect console:** if you add class `w3-hide` inside `gsc-input` class it removes it but I don't know how to do it.

**CSS**

```
.w3-hide{display:none!important}
```

**Jquery** I am trying with no success:

```
$(".gsc-input").addClass("gsc-input w3-hide");
```

Comment: `$(".gsc-input").attr("placeholder", "");` ?

Comment: $(".divcse").hide(); should work.

Comment: @AbhishekK.Upadhyay nope, it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function which continuously blocks the ads while the are being generated.

**GSC google search console** - **block ads in result** :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
is_expired = 0;
$(function (){
var timer = setInterval(hidead, 100);
if (is_expired > 0) {
 clearInterval(timer);
}
}); 

function hidead() {
$(".gsc-adBlock").hide();
};

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I m assuming you would want to hide the placeholder, but you would still want it to be a search bar. Adding  `w3-hide` class to `gsc-i-id1`, **would hide the search bar altogether, leaving it non-typable**. Instead you would need to override the background img (Google's Logo) style which is applied.

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
    $('#gsc-i-id1').removeAttr('placeholder');
    $('#gsc-i-id1').css('background', 'none');

    $('#gsc-i-id1').on('blur', function() {
        $('#gsc-i-id1').css('background', 'none');
    });
});
```

Comment: That works but when I click on the text and again click out of it then the image displays again. See the demo.

Comment: I missed that out. I ve updated my answer. you can attach an onblur event, which removes the logo whenever the logo gets reinserted again

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#gsc-i-id1').attr("placeholder", "");
 $('#gsc-i-id1').css('background-image', 'none');
 $("#gsc-i-id1").blur(function() {
  $('#gsc-i-id1').css('background-image', 'none');
 });
});
```